# Where are the Moon rocks from Apollo?

Tags: moonlanding

There were so many Apollo Missions, and they landed on the moon (so they say). When astronauts came back to Earth from the moon, they brought Moon rock samples. Where are these moon rocks/samples now, and where can we see them?

Comment: can we see them?

Comment: A group of samples were prepared and given to foreign governments as gifts - the [Friendship rock](http://www.collectspace.com/resources/moonrocks_goodwill.html) (the link has a list of the samples that were given out - some are on public display.) Also there are some larger samples that are out "on loan" in various museums worldwide, though some research will be needed to find them all...

Comment: STFC (in the UK) owns some moon rocks and loans them out to schools/colleges with the appropriate security arrangements. I have seen this collection. http://www.stfc.ac.uk/public-engagement/borrow-the-moon/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Space Exploration, but it is not of sufficient quality to migrate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's well-explained on NASA'a web site ... http://curator.jsc.nasa.gov/Lunar/index.cfm

About **380 kg** of rocks and soil were brought back.

Note that ...

> "The **lunar sample building** at Johnson Space Center is the chief repository for the Apollo samples."

http://curator.jsc.nasa.gov/Lunar/laboratory_tour.cfm

About **three hundred** moon rocks were given as gifts by the US to cities and countries around the world, and you can easily find that list, and hence go see them all. (More fun than PokemonGo!)

[List showing where to see moon rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apollo_lunar_sample_displays)

You can usually very easily see one at the local "national museum" in your country.  I've seen maybe five all over the world at the places listed there.

It seems that at least 100 have [gone missing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_sample_displays#Current_fate)!

There are a few moon rocks in the wild and there were **cases of theft** - they would be worth millions of bucks ... [TV show about that](http://www.natgeotv.com/ca/million-dollar-moon-rock-heist).